# Mock access to /asset files

Tags: android, unit-testing, junit, assets

I'm trying to create a test unit for a class accessing a file in `/asset` and, as far as I have experimented, I see no way do that without altering the logic of the class being tested.

What I would like to accomplish is the creation of an environment where I can point my class to the asset file I like (and not the one originally pointed in the code), so that I can run multiple tests with it, so for example, if my original code looks something like:

```
ctx.getAssets().open("config.txt")
```

i can instead open

```
bogus_config.txt
ok_config.txt
nonexisting_config.txt
```

So far I have tried:

- creating a `MockContext`, but since pretty much everything in `AssetManager` is `final`, I see no way to get the served the file I want
- using a `RenamingDelegatingContext` with a specific prefix, but *the prefix doesn't work on asset files it seems...*

Is there a better way (some Java Magik Reflection Trick(Tm) of sorts, for instance) to achieve what I want?

Even though I'm very new to unit testing in general, I know that I could pick any of the following work-around solutions:

- move the file into raw and use Resources (but what will I do when using assets will be mandatory? It would be nice to know...)
- exposing the name of the file in the class and change it within the test unit (just kidding... **ugh!!** **:p**)
- create a public wrap around of my method to use a specific file instead of the one used by default, and prefix the method with `junit_` to document that it is to be used by testing routines only (which is probably what I'll end up doing)

but I still think that the original question might be of some interest, so any suggestion is welcome

Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
  > I see no way do that without altering the logic of the class being tested.
```

I agree but the change would be quite minimal: move the code `ctx.getAssets().open("config.txt")` into a protected method `InputStream openConfig(Context ctx)` which you can easily overide/fake/mock in your tests. If you use Eclipse or Androidstudio mark the statement and execute context-menu Refactor/Extract-Method.

Comment: so, if I got it right, you are suggesting to refactor the class being tested so that I can mock/fake the method used within the class to actually read the file (openConfig in this case)? If that's the case I could separately test openConfig and then the class itself with a fake openConfig, correct?

Comment: yes, you can test "the class itself" with the fake, but i would not create a unittest for "openConfig" because it is trivial and not part of the public api.  "openConfig" is probably already covered by a "happy-day"-integrationtest.

Comment: Good point: as it happens the hardest part I have found in unit testing since I started (a week ago?) is to know what to test, and especially, when to stop... Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

you can use this way

```
class AssetsUtils {

    companion object {

        fun <T> loadResponse(
            path: String,
            tClass: Class<T>?,
            isPrettyPrinting: Boolean? = false,
            isUnitTest: Boolean? = true
        ): T {

            val json = File(
                "src/${if (isUnitTest == true) {
                    "test"
                } else {
                    "androidTest"
                }}/assets/${path}"
            ).bufferedReader().use {
                it.readText()
            }

            val gson = GsonBuilder()
                .serializeNulls()
                .setPrettyPrinting()
                .create()

            val model = gson.fromJson(json, tClass)

            if (isPrettyPrinting == true) {
                println("Load Response ------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------")
                println()
                println("Response file: $path")
                println(gson.toJson(model))
                println()
                println("Model: $model")
                println()
                println("--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------")
            }

            return model
        }
    }
}
```

example:
the file in "C://ProjectA/app/src/test/asstes/mockApi/folder1/user.json"

```
AssetsUtils.loadResponse(
       "mockApi/folder1/user.json",
       UserModel::class.java
)
```